# How can I convert YYYY-WNN to YYYY-MM-DD format where WNN is week number?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset with date format YYY-WNN and I would to convert it to standard date format. I have tried

```
df_vaccine["Date"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df_vaccine["YearWeekISO"] + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")
```

however I am getting this error: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series.

What can I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should instead try using, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(df['YearWeekISO'], format="%Y-%W-%w").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: If the OP has ISO week dates, `format='%G-%V-%u'` would be appropriate

Comment: Im still getting ValueError: time data '2020-W53' does not match format '%G-%V-%u' (match)